# React.js and Typescript return type of a fetch API Response?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, httpresponse, fetch-api

is it somehow possible to check the response type of a fetch API request on runtime? As far as I know, `Response` is always any? Is it possible to throw an error in case it does not match the type or else accept the data? Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

type Test = {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
}

interface TodoData {
  id: number,
  userId: number,
  title: string,
  completed: boolean,
}

type JSONResponse = () => {
    ok?: boolean,
    status: 200 | number,
    json: () => Promise<TodoData> | Promise<TodoData>[];
}

const App: React.FC<Test> = ({name, age}) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData: any = async () => {
      let todos: Response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
      console.log(todos);
      let todoData: JSONResponse = await todos.json();
      console.log({todoData});
    }
    fetchData();  
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Hello {name} your age is {age? age: "not given here."}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you can use axios instead of fetch. Axios comes'with very easy way to type body, response...

Comment: If you want to stick with fetch, could use Joi to define a schema for the response. You can then call `validate()` on the schema against the response data.

Answer (score 0):

Before TypeScript can be executed by Node.js or your Browser, it has to be compiled to JavaScript. Javascript does not unterstand the type annotations from TypeScript, so they have to be removed in this step.

Because your API data is only available at runtime, and TypeScript types are not available at runtime, you cannot typecheck your response data with TypeScript.

You can however teach TypeScript how the data you expect to recieve is structured, and it will prevent you from accessing data in an illegal way.

If you have to validate the response at runtime, something like [JOI](https://joi.dev/) is a good idea. (Thanks to [Robert Hartshorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5302038/robert-hartshorn) for the suggestion).